# python recursion and operator issue

Tags: python, recursion

Hi I am running below code and below is output , I am getting , can someone help me why values of k is increasing after below line as function is not changing anything related to k -

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

line of output where there is confusion-
"
result is: 0 and k is 0
k in if loop is 1
#
result is in if loop 1

---

result is: 1 and k is 1"

@@@@@@@@@ Code - @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

```
def tri_recursion(k):
     print('##')
     print("k is "+ str(k))
     lp=0
     if(k>0):
        print('If loop is' +str(lp))
        lp=lp+1
        result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
        print('k in if loop is ' + str(k) )
        print('#')
        print("result is in if loop " + str(result))
    else:
        print('""')
        result = 0
    print('****')
    print("result is: " +str(result) + " and k is " +str(k))
    return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
abc=tri_recursion(6)
#print('K is :' + k)
print('abc is ' +str(abc))
```

@@@@@ output @@@@@@@@@@@

Recursion Example Results

## #

k is 6
If loop is0

## #

k is 5
If loop is0

## #

k is 4
If loop is0

## #

k is 3
If loop is0

## #

k is 2
If loop is0

## #

k is 1
If loop is0

## #

k is 0
""

---

result is: 0 and k is 0
k in if loop is 1
#
result is in if loop 1

---

result is: 1 and k is 1
k in if loop is 2
#
result is in if loop 3

---

result is: 3 and k is 2
k in if loop is 3
#
result is in if loop 6

---

result is: 6 and k is 3
k in if loop is 4
#
result is in if loop 10

---

result is: 10 and k is 4
k in if loop is 5
#
result is in if loop 15

---

result is: 15 and k is 5
k in if loop is 6
#
result is in if loop 21

---

result is: 21 and k is 6
abc is 21

Comment: also not sure why its coming out of function when value of result in 21 or value of k is 6

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `k` when you pass it into `tri_recursion(k)` as `tri_recursion(k-1)` in the recursive step.

`tri_recusion(k)` is basically the same as `k-0 + k-1 + k-2 + ....k-k`. So `6` will return `6+5+4+3+2+1 = 21` with each step as `0 , 0+1, 0+1+2, ...., 0+1+2+3+4+5+6 == 0,1,3,6,10,15,21`

Comment: My doubt is at this point - when output is showing --- result is: 0 and k is 0 and then suddenly K values changes to 1  note below line in output   -----                                    
 result is:  0 and k is 0                                                                                                   
 k in if loop is 1                                                                                                              
 #                                                                                                                                result is in if loop 1

Comment: def factorial(n):
    print("factorial has been called with n = " + str(n))
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        print('n is :' , n)
        res = n * factorial(n-1)
        print("intermediate result for ", n, " * factorial(" ,n-1, "): ",res)
        return res 

print(factorial(5))

Comment: n is : 2
factorial has been called with n = 1
intermediate result for  2  * factorial( 1 ):  2

###

in above output after "intermediate result for  2  * factorial( 1 ):  2" 
how its getting looped in  and going to "intermediate result for  3  * factorial( 2 ):  6" line  and not to "factorial has been called with n " line